# Application Insights - select on traces/message stop returning value on REST API

Tags: azure-application-insights

My program used to call the REST API to get traces messages field. In order to limit the return data size, we use the "select" clause to only return "trace/message". This was working very well. But since yesterday (March 15th), this function broken. The "trace/message" always return null while there's message. We workaround this by calling the API without "select" clause and that returns everything as expected.

On the API Explorer I tested all the other fields for traces in the "select", and all of them are working as before, even the field "trace/severityLevel". For dependencies table, any field under "dependency" stop working now.

Is there any release for breaking this? What's reason for this change? Are we supposed to not select on them any more? Any guideline for retrieving these fields?

Comment: Can you share the query that you're running in the API?

Comment: here's the cURL generated from the API Explorer:  "https:// api.applicationinsights.io/beta/apps/[appid]/events/traces?timespan=P30D&$select=trace%2Fmessage&$top=5" -H "x-api-key: xxx". (Hided the app id and api key).

Answer (score 0):

You should try the query API - you can select any type of telemetry, and limit the number of returned records:

```
curl "https://api.applicationinsights.io/beta/apps/DEMO_APP/query?query=traces%7C%20where%20timestamp%20%3E%3D%20ago(24h)%7C%20take%2020" -H "x-api-key: DEMO_KEY"
```

Comment: Yes, we could switch to use query API, but that requires code rewrite. However, my question is why the other one stops working. The "GET /Events" also provide the ability to limit the number of returned records using "$top" clause. I didn't see any functionality difference using these two approaches other than this sudden broken.